# Elixir - How can I unquote an array of functions in my macro?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

Disclaimer: I know that it's possible to write code in a simpler manner, but you should understand that I post simplified code to SO.

I have a module `Simple` which uses `Included`:

```
defmodule Simple do
  use Included,
    events: [
      [ 
        name: :start,
        callback: fn(x) -> x * 2 end
      ], [
        name: :finish,,
        callback: fn(x) -> x * 3 ; x end
      ]
    ]
end
```

I want `Included` module to define a function which takes one param for each item in the list above and return a value. So, I'm doing this:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(opts)
    events = Keyword.get(opts, :events)

    quote bind_quoted: [events: events] do
      events
      |> Enum.each(fn(event) ->
        def unquote(event[:name])(x) do
          x
          |> unquote(event[:callback]).()
          |> IO.puts
      end)
    end    
  end
end
```

The problem here is that I receive `invalid quoted expression: #Function<0.105634730`. I tried to implement it another way:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(opts)
    events = Keyword.get(opts, :events)

    events
    |> Enum.each(fn(event) ->
      quote bind_quoted: [event: event] do
        def unquote(event[:name])(x) do
          x
          |> event[:callback].()
          |> IO.puts
         end
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

But in this case I haven't seen functions defined. (No errors, there is no functions `Simple.start/1` and `Simple.finish/1` here).

My questions are:

1. How can I define desired functions?
2. Why did functions not defined in 2nd approach?

Comment: A workaround that works is to escape the `:callback` key of all events before `quote`: `events = for event <- opts[:events] do; Keyword.update!(event, :callback, &Macro.escape/1); end`.

Comment: @Dogbert Unfortunately I got `cannot escape #Function<2.45959719/1 in Included.MACRO>. The supported values are: lists, tuples, maps, atoms, numbers, bitstrings, pids and remote functions in the format &Mod.fun/arity` I tried to implement something similar in iex, same result =(

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2ab20b11fe9f502f2e0c1d693e1625a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why, but inside the `quote` in `Included.__using__/1`, the AST of the function is being converted into an actual function. If you add `IO.inspect(events)` at the start of the `quote`, you'll get:

```
[[name: :start, callback: #Function<0.18558591 in file:c.exs>],
 [name: :finish, callback: #Function<1.18558591 in file:c.exs>]]
```

A workaround I found for this is to escape the `:callback` in the events.

```
defmacro __using__(opts) do
  events = for event <- opts[:events] do
    Keyword.update!(event, :callback, &Macro.escape/1)
  end
  quote bind_quoted: [events: events] do
  ...
end
```

Final code:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    events = for event <- opts[:events] do
      Keyword.update!(event, :callback, &Macro.escape/1)
    end
    quote bind_quoted: [events: events] do
      events
      |> Enum.each(fn(event) ->
        def unquote(event[:name])(x) do
          x
          |> unquote(event[:callback]).()
          |> IO.puts
        end
      end)
    end    
  end
end

defmodule Simple do
  use Included,
    events: [
      [ 
        name: :start,
        callback: fn(x) -> x * 2 end
      ], [
        name: :finish,
        callback: fn(x) -> x * 3 ; x end
      ]
    ]
end

Simple.start 10
Simple.finish 10
```

Output:

```
20
10
```